# images are saving like tmp file in public folder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to add data in db but images saves like tmp file, m storing these pics in ecommmerce\public\images\backend_images\category_images and these real pics are not saving instead their real name in db they are saving in folder like this: https://ibb.co/CHXTm3j .. any solution . here is my code:

store function:

```
    $category = new Category;
    $category->category_name = $request->category_name;
    $category->category_description = $request->category_description;
    $category->category_slug = $request->category_slug;
    $path = $request->file('category_image');
    $image = $path->getClientOriginalName();
    $path->move(public_path('images/backend_images/category_images'));
    $category->category_image = $image;
    $category->save();
```

Comment: Before saving category: $category->category_image = $image;

Comment: thnx and last thing is that m storing these pics in ecommmerce\public\images\backend_images\category_images  and these real pics are not saving instead their real name in db they are saving in folder like this: https://ibb.co/CHXTm3j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are missing the parameter for filename there. Your function to move the original file should be:

```
$path->move(public_path('images/backend_images/category_images'), $image);
```

If you do not provide that parameter, the default value would be temp name of the file rather than it's original name.